# How do I get elements by tag name using dart

Tags: html, css, dart

I want to get simple paragraph element tag using dart programming language?
Here is what I tried.

```
<h1 id="header"></h1>
<p>Hello world</p>



import 'dart:html';

void main() {
var header = querySelector('#header');
header.text = "Hello, World!";
var p = getElementsByTagName("p");




}
```

Comment: Dart won't work this way - Dart is not directly interpreted via browser, you need transpiler or additionally load library interpreting live Dart to JS.

Comment: I am not using it with the browser I am using it with DartPad.

Comment: Does your question says what is wrong, and what is expected, or anything about your enviroment (DartPad) - no. So add all relevant information to your question, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: All I need to know is that how do I get elements by tag name using dart simple thank you just like javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can access document object to get javascript DOM manipulation methods:

```
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
var header = querySelector('#header');
header.text = "Hello, World!";

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
p.forEach((el){
  el.text = 'lolo';
});

}
```